# Leer una lista y crear otra lista con los cuadrados de los elementos distintos al primero en Haskell

Tags: haskell

Soy una novata en haskell y estoy intentando leer de una lista y crear otra con los elementos distintos al primero.
He implementado la siguiente función pero no me funciona:

```
manipuladistintos _ [] = []
manipuladistintos p (x:xs) = if p x then x : takeWhile p xs
                                    else []
```

Gracias,

Comment: Cuando dices *crear otra con los elementos distintos al primero* ¿A qué elementos te refieres?. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de la lista que tienes y el resultado esperado?. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que dices, a tu función `manipuladistintos` sólo se le necesita pasar  un argumento: la lista.

Dicho formalmente, la *signatura* de la función sería la siguiente:

```hs
manipuladistintos :: (Eq a) => [a]
```

Lo que viene a decir que tenemos de argumento una lista de elementos de un tipo genérico `a` que se pueden comparar entre ellos `Eq a`. No nos importa de qué tipo son los argumentos, siempre que puedan compararse para saber si son iguales o no.

La forma más directa de hacer algo así es empleando la función [`filter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Prelude-0.1.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter):

```hs
manipuladistintos :: (Eq a) => [a]
manipuladistintos [] = []
manipuladistintos (x:xs) = filter (/=x) xs
```

Si no se quiere usar filter, se puede usar recursividad:

```hs
manipuladistintos :: (Eq a) => [a]
manipuladistintos [] = []
manipuladistintos [x] = []
manipuladistintos (x:y:xs) | x /= y    = y : manipuladistintos (x:xs)
                           | otherwise = manipuladistintos (x:xs)
```

---

**Editado**:

Como veo que en la pregunta hablas de *"calcular los cuadrados"*, te añado una solución que usa *"comprensiones de lista"* y que, de paso, hace los cuadrados.

```hs
manipuladistintos :: (Eq a) => [a]
manipuladistintos (x:xs) = [ y * y | y <- xs, x /= y ]
```

Comment: Si tengo [1, 3, 1, 5] me tiene que devolver [3, 5], una lista con los elementos de la primera lista que sean distintos al primer elemento, el 1 Gracias

Comment: Pero aquí el resultado no son los _"cuadrados"_ de los elementos diferentes, tal como indicas en el título de la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias ChemaCortes. Lo he entendido!

Comment: Con tu respuesta el tener que calcular los cuadrado es lo menos.

Comment: Ya, pero si hay un modo elegante de hacerlo, mejor. Te completo la respuesta.